# C# abstract class can't create an instance

Tags: c#, abstract-class

I have an abstract class `ControllerBase` and within the common folder there is a public sealed class `People`. I would like to call this `ShowSuccessMessage` within the sealed class but I get an error.

Is this the correct way to call a sealed class?

Sealed class:

```
    Controllers controller = new ControllerBase();
    controller.ShowSuccessMessage("Error");
```

`ControllerBase` class

```
    public abstract class ControllerBase : Controller
    {       
[Dependency] 
        public Helper Helper { get; set; }
        public void ShowSuccessMessage(string message, bool session = false)
        {
            ShowAlertMessage(message, Messages.Success, session);
        }
    }
```

Different controller that can call the `ShowSuccessMessage`:

```
public class EditorController : ControllerBase
```

Comment: What is the error?  Probably something about not being able to create an instance of an abstract class?  Because you can't create an instance of an abstract class.  You'll need a concrete class which inherits from it.  (Or don't make it abstract.)

Comment: Definition of abstract class is that it can't be constructed.

Comment: What gives you the idea that you can instantiate an abstract class?

Comment: Abstract class are made for that purpose to not been instantiate.

Comment: Is this an MVC controller? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Abstract cannot be directly instantiated. Simply, just make your own class, extend the abstract class, and instantiate the class you've made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You may want to look this article over](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/abstract-and-sealed-classes-and-class-members).

The short version is that the point of an abstract class is to define the blue print of what the class will do, and other concrete classes will implement them. This way, you know everything of type AbstractClass will have the same definition, even if they need different behaviors.

By definition, you can't instantiate them--you'd need to definie a class that inherits your abstract base class, and then instantiate THAT. That's why TemplateEditorController can call the method--it inherits the abstract class, but is not itself abstract. Keep following that pattern.

```
// Cannot instantiate
public abstract class ClassOne
{

    public abstract void DoThing();

}


// can instantiate
public class ImplementationClassOne : ClassOne
{

    public abstract override void DoThing()
    {

    // insert code here

    }

}
```

Comment: Do I also need to instantiate the Helper that is a Dependency?

Comment: I believe so--your EditorController will inherit the property Helper, but since it lives in an abstract class it won't be defined (likely giving you a null reference exception when you try to access it). The EditorController will need to assign a value to that property.

Answer (score 4):

The definition of an abstract class if a class that you can't create an instance of. This just isn't going to work. You can either make the class non abstract, use a sub-class of it, or a different class.